# Prevent Ctrl+Tab bubling

Tags: events, actionscript, tabs, flex3

I'm using ToggleButtonBar control for my Flex project. When user focuses on this control with keyboard it allows him to switch tabs with arrow keys, page up/down or Home/end keys. However, I'd like to add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to as a way to switch tabs.
So, I overrode the method keyDownHandler to work with it.

```
override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
  var updateFocusIndex:Boolean = true;

  switch (event.keyCode)
  {
    case Keyboard.TAB:
    {
      if(event.ctrlKey) 
      {
        focusManager.showFocusIndicator = true;
        drawButtonFocus(focusedIndex, false);
        if (event.shiftKey)
        {
          focusedIndex = prevIndex(focusedIndex);
        } 
        else
        {
          focusedIndex = nextIndex(focusedIndex);
        }

        if (focusedIndex != -1)
        {
          drawButtonFocus(focusedIndex, true);
          selectButton(focusedIndex, updateFocusIndex, event);
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      }
      break;
    }
    default:
    {
      super.keyDownHandler(event);
    }
  }
}
```

Now when user press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> my handler is executed, but also standard Tab event is executed, which changes focus. And I don't want that to happen. I want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to only change tabs without losing focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a weird solution here: http://coder.sonicpoets.com/?p=8

It seems that one can invoke FocusEvent from KeyDownHandler, and then in focus event handler with event.preventDefault prevent moving to another component.

So instead of

```
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

I used

```
    isCtrlTab = true;
    this.setFocus();
```

And added

```
    this.addEventListener(FocusEvent.​KEY_FOCUS_CHANGE, focusChange);


    protected function focusChange(event:FocusEvent):void
    {
        if (isCtrlTab)
        {
            isCtrlTab = false;
            event.preventDefault();
        }   
    }
```